# Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

what could be the reason of this error?

this is my code

```
componentDidMount() {
    $.get("/api/v1/schools", function(result) {
        this.setState({
            dataSchools: result,
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: add the jquery script ?

Comment: did you include jQuery library?

Comment: yes, i have included it

Comment: Please god no don't add jquery just to do a xhr request. Use the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) with a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch) why cant i downvote comments

Comment: should the jquery ui be included also?

Comment: @ivarni why downvote a comment?

Comment: @guradio Because telling someone who is using React to add JQuery just to do a GET request is detrimental to the overall quality of the web. We have better APIs now that can be polyfilled for old browsers at a fraction of the size.

Comment: @ivarni then tell it to OP you dont need to downvote comment comment is just suggestion if it wrong dont do it. that is why it is comment not answer :)

Comment: guys guys dont need to fight :) i solved it already.. thanks a lot!

Comment: @treb good to know that, how did you solve that? what was the issue?

Comment: @KishoreBarik , its funny... i just realized that jquery script should be linked first before the react scripts ;)

Comment: its just like as you said @KishoreBarik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I am not recommending use of jquery only for ajax calls in ReactJs application. You can use libraries like *superagent* or *needle* etc.

Coming to your error: that jquery is not identified inside your JSX code. The reason is JS script inclusion precedence. Make sure you are including the jQuery library ahead of your bundle Js(the Js generated using your buldlers like webpack or CommonJs). To be in safer side  keep the script to include the jQuery library before all other libraries. Because there are many other library which depend upon jQuery to function properly.

Hope this helps.